# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in React app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, babeljs

I have a problem with react app. On launch application i;ve got error like below in my chrom console:
[image]

I don't have any idea why, I'm going through almost every topic with this error but nothing help me. This is my code:

package.json

```
{
  "name": " ",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.8",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "antd": "^4.16.6",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "tailwind": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/babel-generator": "^6.25.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.9.1",
    "eslint": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "webpack": "^5.61.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/react", "@babel/typescript", ["@babel/env", { "modules": false }]]
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <base href="/" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>


  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <title> </title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
</body>
</html>
```

can someone tell me what is wrong?

thanks for any help!

PS. I'm using tsx with react/typescript

1. When i'm click on bundle.js 1
   [image]

Comment: For one, in `index.html` it's `<head>`; you missed `<`. Secondly, the error occurred in your tsx file, so please edit your answer with that code.

Comment: I hope that isnt actually all thats in your index.html. if it is it means you deleted some things. Compare what you have against this boilerplate example https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/basic-html5-template-boilerplate-code-example/ Specifically, You may be missing the doctype

Comment: @Bastiat i'm edit and put the whole html file

Comment: ok cool, so, since it's the bundle.js. that s your actual js app. try clicking on the bundle.js: 1 link and see if theres some info in the actual bundle file.

Comment: @Bastiat when i click on bundle.js: 1 then it redirect me to to view with html :/

Comment: @Bastiat ever tried reading the bundle? Not very helpful. Just post your typescript file and see what's happening.

Comment: I'm cannot read my bundle.js, I'm pasting in main post the screenshot of view of the html when i'm click on bundle.js

Comment: @code yes. but, if bundle.js is coming bck with a < as the first characters its highly likely he's somehow getting an html doc of some kind as another answer references (a 404 doc) for some reason which would mean its not a minified js mess, but something much more readable

Comment: Okay, your bundle.js is HTML. It needs to be JavaScript. ;)

Comment: Yes, he should be, but what have i;m wrong that it read html instead of js?

Comment: maybe this is a problem with misssing webpack configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to manually input `%YOUR_URL%/bundle.js` in your browser.

Chances are that the server serves you 404 HTML page instead of the expected JS bundle.

Comment: so I must to put something like `localhost:3000/bundle.js`?

Comment: Yes, I'd try to go to that URL & check whether any JS file is there. If you don't see any JS code on that page - that's the problem.

Comment: Redirect me to blank page :/

Comment: So, now you know that for any reason your JS bundle is missing. There might be plenty of reasons for that ranging from wrong dev server config to incorrect execution sequence of dev scripts.